# Is there a way to backup contents of VM in Google cloud platform to a specific bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I tried taking snapshot of disk attached to VM but there was no option to specify specific GCS bucket location. There is only an option for selecting multi-regional or regional location where the snapshot will be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly exporting a snapshot is not supported.

You can create a disk from the snapshot, next create an image from the disk. You can then export the image to Cloud Storage.

Note: You cannot export Windows images. You cannot export Google created images. Only non-Windows images that you created.

[Exporting a custom image to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image)